# Physical Network attach to specific LXD Container

Tags: 18.04, netplan, lxd

First of all, I am not that experienced in networking. I have three NIC in my system.

My netplan settings:

```
network:
ethernets:
    enp5s0:
        dhcp4: true
    enp3s0:
        dhcp4: false
        addresses: [X.X.X.251/32]
        nameservers: 
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
        routes:
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
            via: X.X.X.249
            on-link: true
    enp2s0:
        dhcp4: false
        addresses: [X.X.X.252/32]
        nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
        routes:
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
            via: X.X.X.249
version: 2
```

Route Table

```
default via X.X.X.249 dev enp3s0 proto static onlink 
default via 192.168.10.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.10.99 metric 100 
10.0.0.0/16 dev lxdbr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.10.0/23 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.99 
192.168.10.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.10.99 metric 100
```

**enp5s0** is connected to local router. **enp3s0** is public IP that I by default wanted to route through.

**enp2s0** is the one by which I want to set the IP X.X.X.252 and want to attach it with a specific lxc container.

I want to get into lxc container If I want to ssh into X.X.X.252 or other traffic.

How Can I do that here?

```
$ lxc network list

+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------+
|  NAME  |   TYPE   | MANAGED | DESCRIPTION | USED BY |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------+
| enp2s0 | physical | NO      |             | 0       |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------+
| enp3s0 | physical | NO      |             | 0       |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------+
| enp5s0 | physical | NO      |             | 0       |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------+
| lxdbr0 | bridge   | YES     |             | 1       |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------+
```

If I attach that to the container,

```
$ lxc network attach enp2s0 container eth0

$ lxc list
+--------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
|  NAME  |  STATE  |         IPV4          | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+--------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| container | RUNNING | 192.168.11.241 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+--------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
```

It doesn't work and instead it routes through local network.

Please guide me where and what should I change for that?

Comment: I had a similar problem setting static IP addresses.. The issue here is your setting the IP address outside of the container.   If you want to use the device on the host then you'll need a bridge and setup up proxies or nat.   However if you want to dedicate the device to the container you disable DHCP and configure the the IP inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Example of assigning a static address to a container once you have disabled the static address and DHCP on the device.

```
lxc stop container
lxc config device add contianer eth0 nic nictype=routed parent= enp2s0 ipv4.address= X.X.X.252
lxc start container
```

Then once its started..

```
lxc exec container -- ip a show dev eth0
2: eth0@if27: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet X.X.X.252/32 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 blah..
```

You'll then need to setup the default correct default route..